Vite HMR update CSS file with Internal Server Error
I am managing my project with Vite. This is an Inertia project, where the backend is PHP and Laravel, and the frontend is JavaScript, TypeScript, and Vue.
Since I added TypeScript to the project, Vite throws an error exclusively when modifying ts files, indicating an issue with the app.css file declared in Inertia. This is not a 404 error, so the file exists, but it is a 500 error:

Error
[vite] Internal server error: Parse error /path/to/project/resources/css/app.css?direct:5929:20.

When I modify js or vue files, there is no such issue.
Since this seems to be a CSS-related problem, it might be relevant to mention that I am using TailwindCSS.
Configurations
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
// plugins
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
// css
import postcssImport from 'postcss-import'
import postcssEach from 'postcss-each'
import postcssNesting from 'postcss-nesting'
import tailwindNesting from 'tailwindcss/nesting'
import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'

export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      laravel({
        input: [
          'resources/css/app.css', // get the error with this file when modify any "dot ts" file
          'resources/ts/app.ts',
        ],
      }),
      vue(),
    ],
    css: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          postcssImport(),
          postcssEach(),
          postcssNesting(),
          tailwindNesting(),
          tailwind(),
        ],
      },
    },
  })
}

tailwind.config.js
export default {
  content: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.{js,vue}',
  ],
}


Since we only added monitoring of js and vue files to the configuration of TailwindCSS, when changing TypeScript files, TailwindCSS does not recompile its class names, which results in an error in the app.css compiled by laravel-vite-plugin to file.
Therefore, the updated version of app.css during the HMR update event will contain an unknown error or errors, which may cause the error message.
The solution is to mark the monitoring of TypeScript files in the tailwind.config.js file.
tailwind.config.js
export default {
  content: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.{js,ts,vue}', // added "./resources/**/*.ts"
  ],
}

